# Relative Layout's Widget Error

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, classcastexception

I am getting this weird error, it seems like every time I edit the position of the child views in my RelativeLayout by code I get a runtime error like FATAL EXCEPTION: MAIN, and a ClassCastException: ChildView's class.

At first it was my ImageView, so I tried moving it using the GUI in Eclipse, then it was my LinearLayout so I did the same, but then it juggles back to the ImageView, and so on.. I wonder what's wrong with my Layout? Here's my main.xml coding:

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/txtVersion"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:padding="10dp"
>     android:text="version 1.0"
>     android:textColor="#000000"
>     android:textSize="15sp"
>     android:textStyle="bold" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/txtLogo"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:background="@drawable/logo_background"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:padding="20dp"
>     android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>     android:paddingRight="20dp"
>     android:paddingTop="5dp"
>     android:text="Ngaji Yuk"
>     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
>     android:textSize="25sp"
>     android:textStyle="bold" />
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>     android:paddingRight="20dp"
>     android:paddingTop="5dp" >
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btnRead"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:background="@drawable/button_background"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:padding="20dp"
>         android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>         android:paddingLeft="20dp"
>         android:paddingRight="20dp"
>         android:paddingTop="5dp"
>         android:text="Mulai Ngaji"
>         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
>         android:textSize="20sp"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btnIndex"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:background="@drawable/button_background"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:padding="20dp"
>         android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>         android:paddingLeft="20dp"
>         android:paddingRight="20dp"
>         android:paddingTop="5dp"
>         android:text="Indeks"
>         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
>         android:textSize="20sp"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btnAbout"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:background="@drawable/button_background"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:padding="20dp"
>         android:paddingBottom="5dp"
>         android:paddingLeft="20dp"
>         android:paddingRight="20dp"
>         android:paddingTop="5dp"
>         android:text="Tentang Aplikasi"
>         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
>         android:textSize="20sp"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />
>
> </LinearLayout>
>
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/imgMamat"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
> ```

There is no coding in my MainActivity except assigning variable and that's only to the Buttons inside the LinearLayout.

Oh and do excuse me if it's a silly question, I'm a total beginner in Android, thank you.

edit: Here's my Logcat:

> 05-18 11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 05-18
>   11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.rangga.elearning.ngaji/com.rangga.elearning.ngaji.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout 05-18
>   11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   05-18 11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   05-18 11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 05-18
>   11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   05-18 11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 05-18
>   11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 05-18 11:17:08.920:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(516):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 05-18
>   11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-18
>   11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 05-18 11:17:08.920:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(516):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   05-18 11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 05-18
>   11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-18 11:17:08.920:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(516): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.widget.LinearLayout 05-18 11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516):
>     at
>   com.rangga.elearning.ngaji.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
>   05-18 11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   05-18 11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   05-18 11:17:08.920: E/AndroidRuntime(516):    ... 11 more

Cleaning the project seems to fixed it. It's kinda annoying when problems like this show up, even though all the codes shows no error >.<

Comment: sorry I'll be going out for an hour or so, I'll check back when I get home. Thanks.

Comment: I did but it just doesn't show up, dunno why. It's fixed though by cleaning it, thank you all :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try clean and build, it may be due to some previous refences of the xml views remain

Comment: Thanks dude, it works. But this kind of problem is kinda annoying, there should be no error if the coding is right >.<

Comment: Lol, thats why its always recommended, that you should clean project before building, if you have made some changes into resources.

Comment: Cool dude, I'll clean it every time I make some nasty changes. Thanks again hey, legend! :D